# Unit-testing variables in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In my project I use angular.
Variables are initialized in the constructor of one of the components:

```
constructor(
  private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyComponent>,
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
  private fb: FormBuilder
) {
  this.array1 = this.data.filter(item => item.active);
  this.array2 = this.data.filter(item => !item.active);
}
```

in component.spec.ts I have:

```
class MatDialogRefMock {
  close() {
    return {};
  }
}

const matDialogDataMock = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'name',
    active: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name2',
    active: false
  }
];

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TestComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: matDialogDataMock },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useClass: MatDialogRefMock }
      ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    dialogRef = TestBed.inject(MatDialogRef);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

How I can mock the data and remove the error?

P.S. There is a definition of mock data `matDialogDataMock` and `MatDialogRefMock` in the code.

Off: I don't know why, when I edit the code, I get the message: 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'

Comment: You have not shown matDialogDataMock definition, might it be that you have forgotten to initialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was found.
If anyone has the same message - `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` should have been as an object, not as an array.

In my case:

```
providers: [
  { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: { data: matDialogDataMock } },
  { provide: MatDialogRef, useClass: MatDialogRefMock }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define matDialogDataMock and MatDialogRefMock to be injected when TestComponent is instantiated.

```
 providers: [
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: matDialogDataMock },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useClass: MatDialogRefMock }
      ]
```

If you pass this (just to check it works) you wont get the filter error

```
  providers: [
    { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
    { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: [] },
  ],
```

Comment: There is a definition of mock data in the code.